# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): URL is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, api, constructor

I've Used API and updated my state, so now I have an object called animals which contains functions from the API:

```
animals = {
bird: randomBird(),
cat: randomCat(),
dog: randomDog(),
ect...
}
```

Now for example, randomCat() function looks like this:

```
function randomCat() {

        var request = async () => { 
            var res = await get('https://aws.random.cat/meow'); 
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.body;
            } else { 
                console.error(`An error occured: ${res.error}`);
            }
        }

        var url = request().then(body => body.file);
        return url; 
}
```

So I suppose to use this function to get an url.

Now, if I try to call it like this:

```
const cat = this.state.animals.cat;
cat();
```

I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): URL is not a constructor.`

But as I check for typeof cat, I get that it is a function, so how do I call it?

Comment: `url` returns a promise.  `cat()` is same as `request().then(body => body.file)()`.  it should be `cat.then()`

Comment: I changed cat() to cat.then(body => console.log(body)). The error remains the same.

Comment: Please update question using codesnippet functionality in editor. right now it's pieces of codes can't really replicate. or use http://www.codesandbox.io if you're using react.